# I can't dynamically add items to List. SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-button

I can't dynamically add items to List. SwiftUI.
I'm new at SwiftUI, so i don't know why it's not working

Don't pay attention to lorem

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

```
import SwiftUI

struct UpdateList : View {
    var updates = updateData
    @ObservedObject var store = UpdateStore(updates: updateData)
**Update func doesn't work(It doesn't add anything)**
    func addUpdate() {
        store.updates.append(Update(image: "Certificate1", title: "New Title", text: "New Text", date: "JUL 1"))
    }
    
    func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        store.updates.swapAt(source.first!, destination)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
**List Code**
            List {
                ForEach(store.updates) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: UpdateDetail(title: item.title, image: item.image, text: item.text)) {
                        HStack(spacing: 12.0) {
                            Image(item.image)
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                                .background(Color("background"))
                                .cornerRadius(20)
                            
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                Text(item.title)
                                    .font(.headline)
                                Text(item.text)
                                    .lineLimit(2)
                                    .lineSpacing(4)
                                    .font(.subheadline)
                                    .frame(height: 40.0)
                                Text(item.date)
                                    .font(.caption)
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.vertical, 8.0)
                }
                .onDelete { index in
                    self.store.updates.remove(at: index.first!)
                }
                .onMove(perform: move)
                
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Updates"))
            .toolbar{
                ToolbarItem{
                    HStack {
                        Button(action: addUpdate) {
                            Text("Add Update")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        }
                        .padding(8)
                        .background(Color("background3"))
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                        EditButton()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct UpdateList_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        UpdateList()
    }
}

struct Update: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var image: String
    var title: String
    var text: String
    var date: String
}

var updateData = [
    Update(image: "Illustration1", title: "SwiftUI", text: "Learn how to build custom views and controls in SwiftUI with advanced composition, layout, graphics, and animation. See a demo of a high performance, animatable control and watch it made step by step in code. Gain a deeper understanding of the layout system of SwiftUI.", date: "JUN 26")
    



UpdateStore file
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class UpdateStore : ObservableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    var updates: [Update] {
        didSet{
            didChange.send()
        }
    }
    
    init(updates: [Update] = []) {
        self.updates = updates
    }
}
```

**I'm expecting add a new list item everytime I tap the button("Add Update")**

Comment: Your code works well for me, I get additional `Update` every time I click
 the "Add Update" Button. On MacOS 13.3, Xcode 14.3 beta, tested on real ios 16.3 devices (not Previews), and macCatalyst. It could be different on older systems. I would suggest using `@StateObject var store ...`. Can you show the code for `UpdateStore` and how you declare `updates` in it.

Comment: What is `UpdateStore`? It requires a `@Published` property `updates` to refresh the view. And please use `@StateObject` rather than `@ObservedObject`to initialize a *source of truth*. If you are new to SwiftUI you certainly don't want to use outdated terminology.

Comment: Check UpdateStore file at the end

Comment: as mentioned, use `@Published var updates: [Update] = []` and `@StateObject var store = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine for me. Do you have @Published set on your Update? Also some minor tweaks in the view initialisation. You can not pass a view variable in to the class on init.

```
class UpdateStore: ObservableObject {

@Published var updates: [Update] = []

}

struct UpdateList : View {
var updates = updateData
@ObservedObject var store = UpdateStore()
//**Update func that doesn't work(It doesn't add anything**
func addUpdate() {
    store.updates.append(Update(image: "Certificate1", title: "New Title", text: "New Text", date: "JUL 1"))
}

func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
    store.updates.swapAt(source.first!, destination)
}

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
//**List Code**
        List {
            ForEach(store.updates) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()) {
                    HStack(spacing: 12.0) {
                        Image(item.image)
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                            .background(Color("background"))
                            .cornerRadius(20)
                        
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(item.title)
                                .font(.headline)
                            Text(item.text)
                                .lineLimit(2)
                                .lineSpacing(4)
                                .font(.subheadline)
                                .frame(height: 40.0)
                            Text(item.date)
                                .font(.caption)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 8.0)
            }
            .onDelete { index in
                self.store.updates.remove(at: index.first!)
            }
            .onMove(perform: move)
            
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Updates"))
        .toolbar{
            ToolbarItem{
                HStack {
                    Button(action: addUpdate) {
                        Text("Add Update")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                    }
                    .padding(8)
                    .background(Color("background3"))
                    .cornerRadius(8)
                    EditButton()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
}
```